# WMD + Rails: how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was looking at http://wmd-editor.com/ but couldn't figure out how to use this in rails. I am pretty new. If someone can lead me to the right direction that would be very appreiciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do much.

Just make a form with a `<textarea>` for the attribute you want to edit with WMD, include wmd.js like this `javascript_include_tag wmd.js`

Taken from WMD readme.txt:

> By default, WMD will turn the first
>   textarea on your page into an editor. 
>   You can modify this behavior with the
>   `wmd-ignore` class, described below.